# F# How to use preload child records using Sql Type Provider

Tags: sql-server, f#, type-providers

I'm using the F# SqlDataConnection data provider to access a database. The code works fine except that it goes to the database for every single nested record. How do I get the query to prefetch some of these records

```
module Local =
    type Db = SqlDataConnection<"Server=.;Database=CCTFundDb;Trusted_Connection=True">
    let db = 
        let ctx = Db.GetDataContext()
        let dataOptions = Data.Linq.DataLoadOptions()
        dataOptions.LoadWith<Db.ServiceTypes.MemberSubscriptions>(fun p->p.AccountingBooks.AccountingBookEntries |> box)
        ctx.DataContext.LoadOptions <- dataOptions
        ctx
    let _ =  db.DataContext.Log <- Console.Out
```

If I remove the `|> box`, it gives the error that it is expecting `obj`. When I execute in fsx, it complains about the expression.

How do I do this? If it is not possible, is there another type provider that supports loading the data in batches?

Comment: As an alternative I can recommend [SqlClient Provider](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.SqlClient). It is more transparent than linq to sql

Comment: Cool. I'll check it out.

Comment: @ntr Worked as expected. Can you post as an actual answer to I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative I can recommend [SqlClient Provider](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.SqlClient). It generates types based on sql you want to execute and the best part is that you don't need to know linq-to-sql(or other ORMs) internals to work with types generated from database.